# Как обойти блокировку бота flood control RetryAfter в aiogram?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram, telegram, блокировки

Пишу бота для телеграм, который кидает картинки в группу. Иногда происходит ситуация, что картинок много и бот выхватывает ошибку "flood control". Я понимаю, что можно обработать ошибку try:except или dp.error_handler и бот не прекратит работу, но при возникновении этой ошибки он и прекратит отправлять картинки на время указанное в сообщении.

Можно ли как-то предотвратить вызов этой ошибки, к примеру поставив asyncio.sleep(1) или больше по времени? Есть ли какой-то способ?

Часть кода:

```
...
for i in photo_list:
    photo = types.InputFile(i)
    try:
        await bot.send_photo(chat_id, photo=photo)
    except RetryAfter:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У исключения `RetryAfter` есть поле [timeout](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/f20e6ca0bde0453924fe4882b1f999ea91a1df1d/aiogram/utils/exceptions.py#L569)

Я бы сделал [задержку на значение](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/df294e579f104e2ae7e9f37b0c69490782d33091/examples/broadcast_example.py#L40) этого поля

Пример:

```
for i in photo_list:
    photo = types.InputFile(i)
    try:
        await bot.send_photo(chat_id, photo=photo)
    except RetryAfter as e:
        await asyncio.sleep(e.timeout)
```